# Swift MVVM - use protocol to handle viewModel events

Tags: swift, mvvm, architecture, swift-protocols

I'm trying to use MVVM with delegate protocols. When something changes in the view model I want to trigger it in the view controller.

When I want to use protocols to handle the view model's event on a view controller, I can not set the protocol to the view controller for my view model class.
It gives me the error:

> Argument type `(SecondViewController) -> () -> SecondViewController` does not conform to expected type `SecondViewModelEvents`

How can I do this the right way?

Here is the code for my view model:

```swift
protocol SecondViewModelEvents {
    func changeBackground()
}

class SecondViewModel:NSObject {

    var events:SecondViewModelEvents?

    init(del:SecondViewModelEvents) {
        self.events = del
    }

    func loadDataFromServer() {
        self.events?.changeBackground()
    }

}
```

And for my view controller class:

```swift
class SecondViewController: UIViewController,SecondViewModelEvents {

    let viewModel = SecondViewModel(del: self) //Argument type '(SecondViewController) -> () -> SecondViewController' does not conform to expected type 'SecondViewModelEvents'

    @IBAction func buttonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        self.viewModel.loadDataFromServer()
    }

    func changeBackground() {
        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying to initialize the view model variable and pass the view controller as a delegate which at this point is not fully initialized.

Try checking out the very informative and very detailed [Initialization](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Initialization.html) page in the official Swift language guide.

Since this is a protocol used for this specific purpose, we can safely constrain it to classes (notice the `: class` addition to your code.

```swift
protocol SecondViewModelEvents: class {
    func changeBackground()
}
```

It's good practice to use more descriptive naming, and also using weak references for delegate objects in order to avoid strong reference cycles.

```swift
class SecondViewModel {

    weak var delegate: SecondViewModelEvents?

    init(delegate: SecondViewModelEvents) {
        self.delegate = delegate
    }

    func loadDataFromServer() {
        delegate?.changeBackground()
    }

}
```

You can try to use an optional view model, which will get initialized in an appropriate place, like `awakeFromNib()`:

```swift
class SecondViewController: UIViewController, SecondViewModelEvents {

    var viewModel: SecondViewModel?

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()

        viewModel = SecondViewModel(delegate: self)
    }

    @IBAction func buttonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        viewModel?.loadDataFromServer()
    }

    func changeBackground() {
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    }

}
```

Or an alternative approach would be to initialize a non-optional view model in the `UIViewController` required initializer:

```swift
    // ...

    var viewModel: SecondViewModel

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)

        self.viewModel = SecondViewModel(delegate: self)
    }

    // ...
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `lazy` initialization as,

```
lazy var viewModel =  SecondViewModel(del: self)
```

**OR**

```
lazy var viewModel = { [unowned self] in SecondViewModel(del: self) }()
```

Comment: Why I need to use lazy ?

Comment: Because you are using `self` to initialize the stored property which is not possible without making it `lazy`.

Comment: Is there is a best practice about trigger functions-datas from viewModel on viewController?

Comment: I'll suggest to implement your own binding api and use that instead of using `Rx-Swift`. You can check [this](https://codeburst.io/swift-mvvm-two-way-binding-win-b447edc55ff5).